# Get Reponse of a Update Query in win form application

Tags: winforms, ms-access-2010

Is there any way i can get response of a Update query that how many rows has been affected ?

**What I want is..**

I am updating some data in Access 2010 DB table using Win Form Application, In access if i run this query it shows alert that 10 rows has been affected. how can I get this response in from application to maintain a log file of affected rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method of your ODBC/SQL/ Command object. It returns the no. of rows affected by your query.

```
int rec = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

it is easy my dear friend use a **Trigger** in access on update. MS Access lets you design the trigger according to your need and **can also return number of rows affected by update**. here is a link where you can learn to create trigger

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqFYvsemoZo